# Angular 2 правильное и ошибочное использование модулей сервисов и компонентов?

Tags: angular2

Во-первых, большое спасибо.
Теперь 2 вопроса 
1й вопрос о структуре.
Я новичек. Я читал о модулях, компонентах сервисах, Но до сих пор не до конца понимаю, какие задачи свойственны каждой из этих сущностей, а какие чужды. Особенно буду благодарен за ответ в такой форме: вот эти задачи для модуля, а вот эти для модуля нельзя, лучше поручить это компоненту. И так далее. Можно ли одному сервису дать задачу делать оба запроса на разные серверы или нужно писать два сервиса? 
и почему?

2й вопрос практический. 
Я пишу учебную программу запрос к API погоды. Пользователь вводит cityName. 
Первый запрос посылаю к серверу, где лежит файл json я посылаю name налету, получаю список городов, у которых есть такие же буквы в имени. Делаю живую выпадающую подсказку для пользователя.

Например: набрали kongo, выпадает подсказка:

```
    0: "{"id":202239,"name":"Gikongoro, RW"}"
    1: "{"id":1064234,"name":"Ikongo, MG"}"
    2: "{"id":212360,"name":"Kongolo, CD"}"
    3: "{"id":2359142,"name":"Kongoussi, BF"}"
```

Потом после клика пользователя на выбранный город. отправляю его id на сервер погоды. Получаю от API погоду json. отрисовываю ответ прогноз погоды.

ВОПРОС: сколько и каких модулей должно быть в оптимальной структуре этого приложения и у какого компонента и сервиса какая должна быть задача? Кланяюсь заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен, но постараюсь на него ответить, как вы сами знаете правильно поставленный вопрос - это половина ответа.

Модули в Angular - довольно сложная тема, но постараюсь объяснить простыми словами. Концепция модулей в Angular в первую очередь придумана для реализации принципа "разделение ответственности". Каждый модуль это черный ящик, который инкапсулирует в себе определенную бизнес логику. На практике, конечно, модули используются для повышения производительности крупных приложений благодаря возможности загрузки по требованию (lazy-loading). У модулей нет никаких задач и не нужно им  ничего поручать или писать какой-то код, у модулей нет жизненного цикла. Цель модуля в первую очередь заключается в том, чтобы скомпилировать компоненты, объявленные в `declarations`, у каждого модуля есть свой инстанс класса `Compiler`, так же вторичная цель модуля - это управление механизмом DI (внедрение зависимостей), в рантайме модуль так же является инжектором.

```
@NgModule()
export class AppModule {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        console.log(injector.constructor.name === 'NgModuleRef_'); // true
    }
}
```

Если заинжектить зависимость по токену `Injector` в модуль - то в итоге модуль получить ссылку на самого себя.

Команда Google, а именно Мишко Хевери (тимлид Angular) еще при разработке 1.х Angular решил предоставить людям возможность использовать архитектуру SCA (service-component architecture). Если будем говорить в данный момент об Angular 2+ - то перед сервисами так же стоит цель изолировать логику, которую можно шарить между компонентами, делая ее `reusable`. Любой сервис должен делать что-то конкретное.

[image]

Вы можете полностью всю логику написать в 1 компоненте, и запросы делать из компонента, и манипулировать большими данными, но все это портит дизайн, а декомпозиция - прежде всего. В компонентах нужно всего навсего реализовывать логику обновления данных.

[image]

В случае с Angular - VM (view-model) - это промежуточный слой между данными и представлением, которое видит конечный пользователь, задача VM - обновлять модель, всю остальную логику вы выносите в сервисы. `Можно ли одному сервису дать задачу делать оба запроса на разные серверы или нужно писать два сервиса?` - на ваше усмотрение.

**UPD:**

Нет такого понятия как архитектура компонентов, есть архитектура приложения. По поводу вашего приложения "прогноз погоды" я бы просто создал 1 сервис для работы с API, назвал бы его `WeatherService`, и несколько компонентов, один компонент для отображения погоды после того, как пользователь выберет город, компонент поиска и компонент подсказок. Для всех приложений нет какой-то определенной структуры, Angular - изоморфная платформа, которая позволяет спроектировать архитектуру любой сложности. Весь этот высокоуровневый дизайн начинает проектироваться после определения проблемы / выработки требований / создания плана конструирования, это все очень ситуативно.

На диаграмме компоненты ничего не отдают, эти стрелки в принципе можно назвать делегатами, но на самом деле они показывают что компоненты не общаются напрямую с менеджером состояний, а используют промежуточный слой (посредник), хотя в свою очередь менеджер после проделанной работы может известить компонент с какой-то информацией. Данная диаграмма - это маленький фундамент любого энтерпрайз Angular приложения сегодня, от нее уже дальше все отталкиваются.

Comment: Спасибо, за отзыв. Не могли бы поделиться, какую архитектуру компонентов вы бы создавали для решения второй половины моего вопроса Приложение Прогноз Погоды. Мне это нужно для практического закрепления вашего объяснения. 

Может быть вы знаете где почитать документацию с примерами, типа: для такого приложение применима такая-то структура, а для другого другая и много примеров.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: И еще, на вашей первой диаграмме
 
[компоненты] что-то отдают 

[сервисам для работы с браузерным ip] и 

[Экшенам(что это?)] и что-то получают от 

[Менеджера состояний (Redux) (опционально)], 

а с другими элементами напрямую не общаются? или это частный случай?
И что такое слои? Я понимаю, что вы меня можете послать в гугл, но я оттуда не вылезаю уже 4 недели и мне очень хочется это узнать. И вот наконец решился просить помощи у вас.

Comment: @A.Victor пометьте ответ галочкой, если он решает вашу проблему

Comment: "Если заинжектить зависимость по токену Injector в модуль - то в итоге модуль получить ссылку на самого себя." - этого предложения я не понял. Ну да ладно. Но вот со вторым помогите. Когда вы отвечаете "на ваше усмотрение" или "ситуативно", мне это не помогает. Какое у меня может быть усмотрение, если я новичек. На мое усмотрение все вообще нужно написать в одном файле. Но вы же почему-то строите структуру. Вопрос: какую структуру на ваше усмотрение вы выбрали бы для приложения "Прогноз погоды" описанного мной во второй половине вопроса???